# JavaFX XYChart warnings

Tags: java, javafx

Lets take this small example, what are those warnings / what am i doing wrong here?

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'XYChart.Data'
Unchecked assignment: 'javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data' to 'javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data<java.lang.String,java.lang.Number>'
Unchecked call to 'Data(X, Y)' as a member of raw type 'javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data'
```

This would be the code

```
private final XYChart.Series<String, Number> courseSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
private final LinkedList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> courseSeriesTimespan = new LinkedList<>();
@FXML
public BarChart<String, Number> course;

private void test(){
    courseSeriesTimespan.get(1).getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jän", 1));
}
```

Comment: To expand on the given answer: The `XYChart.Data` class is also a generic type, whose type arguments should match the type arguments of the `XYChart.Series` it's going to be added to. You are using the raw type, hence the warning, and the fix is to parameterize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameterized type

```
courseSeriesTimespan.get(1).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Jän", 1));
```

**Update**. Or without specifying specific types

```
courseSeriesTimespan.get(1).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Jän", 1));
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I would expect you could just use `<>` instead of explicitly specifying the types.

Comment: @Slaw You are right. I updated the answer